# imacros display message to user if page or text not found

Tags: imacros

My current imacros code calls a URL from a datasource.  Should the URL not load (scheduled downtime or wifi is broken) it must display the relevant message to the user.  I am unable to get any information on how to display the message to the user when there is downtime or the wifi is down.  Below is what I got so far:

```
VERSION BUILD=844 RECORDER=CR
SET !FILE_PROFILER YES
'Clear the Cache and history'
CLEAR
'Close any open tabs'
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 13
'Navigate to the EBU Online URL'
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
CMDLINE !DATASOURCE Apps.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO = {{!COL1}}
WAIT SECONDS=15
'There are no credentials for logging onto EBU Online'
```

Would appreciate any feedback, as I am new to imacros.

Windows 10
Chrome Version 61.0.3163.79 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display a message when there's no required text on the page, the following macro may help:

```
SET myText "imacros display message bla-bla-bla"
SET myScript "document.body.textContent.includes('{{myText}}') ? '' : alert('NO  \"{{myText}}\"  FOUND!');"
URL GOTO=javascript:{{myScript}}undefined;
```

Comment: Shugar, thanks for the answer, but the alert is not displaying when the text is not found

Comment: Try to play the edited macro on **this page**. Does it display an alert dialog?

Comment: @ Shugar, the last edit you did worked.  Thank you very much

Comment: Nice to hear :)